# Problem with the proper functioning of the script

Tags: powershell

I have a request if anyone could help find a bug in setting the virtual memory by the script, if you have less than 8GB of ram, the script instead of setting 8GB goes to setting the variant for 16GB of operating memory

```
$Result = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1GB
$DriveLetter = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Volume | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.PageFilePresent}).DriveLetter[0]
switch ($Result)
{
    {$PSItem -le 7}
    {
        Write-Verbose "Masz $($PSItem) GB pamięci! Zmiana pliku stronicowania na poczatkowy: 8 GB - maks .: 8 GB" -Verbose
 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
 
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Set-CimInstance -Property @{AutomaticManagedPageFile = $false}
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.SettingID -eq "pagefile.sys @ $($DriveLetter):"} | Set-CimInstance -Property @{
            InitialSize = 8192
            MaximumSize = 8192
        }
    }
    {$PSItem -le 31}
    {
        Write-Verbose "Masz $($PSItem) GB pamięci! Zmiana pliku stronicowania na poczatkowy: 16 GB - Max 16 GB" -Verbose
 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
 
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Set-CimInstance -Property @{AutomaticManagedPageFile = $false}
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.SettingID -eq "pagefile.sys @ $($DriveLetter):"} | Set-CimInstance -Property @{
            InitialSize = 16384
            MaximumSize = 16384
        }
    }
    {$PSItem -ge 32}
    {
        Write-Verbose "Masz $($PSItem) GB pamięci! Zmiana pliku stronicowania na poczatkowy: 8 GB - Max 8 GB" -Verbose
 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
 
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Set-CimInstance -Property @{AutomaticManagedPageFile = $false}
        Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.SettingID -eq "pagefile.sys @ $($DriveLetter):"} | Set-CimInstance -Property @{
            InitialSize = 8192
            MaximumSize = 8192
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: You have TWO "Less than" conditions on the same variable. How do you know it's running the right one? Less than 7 is also less than 31 :). This is probably one situaiton where using If..ElseIf...Then is a better strategy than Switch.

Comment: If you converted this to `If..ElseIf...` and inverted the order, then this would be easier to solve.  `if ($PSitem -ge 32){}...elseIf ($PSItem -ge 8 -and $PSItem -lt 16)...Else{#must be below 8 gb}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `break` on your `switch` statement, all possibilities are being evaluated without a `break`. By the way, you say lower than 8 yet in your statement I see lower or equal to 7. In any case, suppose you have 4Gb of RAM, with your statement you would enter into the first condition because 4 is lower or equal to 7 and you would also enter into the second condition because 4 is lower or equal to 31.

When working with `switch` just remember, it's very important to use breaks if you don't want to keep evaluating the following conditions.

Try the code below with and without `break` and see what happens:

```
$eval=4

switch($eval)
{
    {$_ -le 7}
    {
        "$_ is lower or equal to 7"
        break
    }
    {$_ -le 31}
    {
        "$_ is lower or equal to 31"
        break
    }
    Default
    {
        "$_ is higher than 31"
    }
}
```